# How do I count an array until a certain integer(Java)?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a program where I have an array where the values are inputted by the user using Scanner, and then I need to add the value of all of the integers together. How would I go about doing this, as there isn't a set length for the array.

Comment: An array always has a set length. Hence array. Nonetheless try it yourself first and then show us what you have tried. Welcome to SO :)

Comment: Why would an array be needed?

Comment: If you want to have a list of values, but you don't know how many values there will be, take a look at [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).  If you want to add up everything in an ArrayList, you can just use a stream, like so: `arraylist.stream().reduce((i, j) -> i + j).get();`.  I'll let you write the rest of the code :)

Comment: Or never store the values. Just keep a variable that is initially set to zero, but each time you enter a new int, you add this value to the sum.

Answer (score 0):

You can either prompt the user for the length of the array or define a certain value, e.g. `-1`, to signify the end of the input.

Option 1 ([Demo](https://ideone.com/TOP4MT)):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("How many numbers do you want to sum?");
int len = sc.nextInt();
sc.nextLine();
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
    sum += sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();
}
System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);
```

Option 2 ([Demo](https://ideone.com/BFnUaZ)):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter numbers to sum. Enter -1 to stop.");
int sum = 0;
int num;
while((num = sc.nextInt()) != -1){
    sc.nextLine();
    sum += num;
}
System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);
```

Comment: @Ryan No problem.

Comment: @Ryan Would you mind [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) my answer if it solved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Best approach would be storing integer values in list structure.

```
final List<Integer> values = new ArrayList();
```

The list structure dynamically expands after add new element:

```
values.add(newUserValue);
```

If you use Java in version 8 and above, you can use sum() method from Stream API:

```
final Integer sum = values.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
```

If you use Java in version below 8 you can write function which iterates through every list element and sum them:

```
int sum(final List<Integer> values) {
   int sum = 0;
   for(final Integer value : values) {
      sum += value;
   }
   return sum;
}
```